# Range of unbounded operator is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

Suppose I have a densely defined symmetric positive operator $T$. I want to show that the range of $T+I$ is closed if $T$ is closed. I've been able to show that $\| x\|^2 + \| Tx\|^2 \leq \| (T+I)x\|^2$ and understand that we need to consider a convergent sequence $(T+I)x_n \to y$ and show that $y = (T+I)x$, where $x$ is the limit of $x_n$.

The inequality just doesn't come out.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $L : \mathcal{G}(T)\rightarrow\mathcal{R}(T+I)$ defined by
$$
          L(x,Tx) = Tx+x.
$$

Your inequality, combined with the triangle inequality gives
$$
            \|Tx\|^2+ \|x\|^2 \le \|(T+I)x\|^2 \le 2(\|Tx\|^2+\|x\|^2),
$$
which proves that $L$ is a bicontinuous bijection. Because $\mathcal{G}(T)$ is complete, then the range of $T+I$ must be complete, which proves that $\mathcal{R}(T+I)$ is closed.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{G}(T)$?

Comment: @David : The graph $\mathcal{G}(T)$ of $T$ consists of order pairs of domain and range, with the subspace norm inherited from $X\times X$, where $X$ is the underlying space.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in Dom(T)$ a converging sequence, with limit point $x$, such that $(T+I)x_n$ converges to some $y$. Note that:
\begin{equation}
\|Tx_n -(y-x)\| \leq \|Tx_n + x_n - y \|+\|x-x_n\| = \|(T+I)x_n -y \| +\|x-x_n\|
\end{equation}

So $Tx_n$ converges to $y-x$. Because $T$ is closed, $x \in Dom(T)$ and $Tx = y -x \Rightarrow (T+I)x = y$.